# Why are all my lists none when I pass them to a function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that requires me to pass more than one list to a function. But when I  return each list in the function I passed it to, they come up as 'none'. 
This is a coding of how one of my lists are made then passed.

```
def somelist(magslist):
    return magslist

def main():
    alist = []
    for i in range(5):
        alist.append(i)
    somelist(alist)

main()
```

Comment: How can you tell that they're None? I don't see a print statement anywhere.

Comment: Your `somelist` method just returns the argument, essentially not doing anything...

Comment: @FarmerJoe I suspect this is a quick and dirty test. The fault lies in main()

Comment: @kdopen they state that they are concerned about what is return from the function they are passing to.  This code creates a list `alist = [0,1,2,3,4]` not `None`.  There is not really any indication where he is seeing `None` so I can only conclude this is a case of an attempt at a simplified example which does not demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @FarmerJoe Specifically they state "I'm trying to make a program that requires me to pass more than one list to a function." so someist() is the receiver of a list and simply returns it as a test - as such is it perfectly fine. The issue with "None" is that main() exits without returning anything .. so what does Python print out after calling it? "None"

Comment: @kdopen You are assuming a print statement when there is not one.

Comment: @kdopen I don't know why you are arguing with me.  You are making assumptions to provide your answer, but questions here should provide all relevant information.  Even the quote you provided says they would like to "pass more than one list to a function" they are not passing lists to the `main` function.  They are passing lists to the `somelist` function.

Comment: @FarmerJoe It says "to **a** function" - indefinite article - not "to main()". I'm not arguing with (or against) you. I'm arguing on behalf of the OP. I just want them to understand where they went wrong. Stackoverflow is not just wikipedia - it's should be here to help people learn. It is fairly obvious from what they said that they were running in a REPL (else, main() wouldn't show None and - as you said - they wouldn't know it because of no print)

Comment: @kdopen do you know how to read? "they are not passing lists to the main function"

Comment: @kdopen I am reading their code and I see only one line where a list is passed to a function, and it is NOT to `main` it IS to `somelist`

Comment: @kdopen Where are you getting that I said they are passing to the main function, are you just reading my comments and then imaginging something other than what I said?

Comment: @kdopen I am not saying you are wrong, I am not even talking about your answer, or any solution. I was originally telling OP that the example he provided does not do anything because you may be smart enough to see that the problem does not lie in the function `somelist` but as of right now his question indicates that it does.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def somelist(magslist):
    return magslist

def main():
    alist = []
    for i in range(5):
        alist.append(i)
    print somelist(alist)   # print it here only, for python3 use print with brackets

main()
```

Or:

```
def somelist(magslist):
    return magslist

def main():
    alist = []
    for i in range(5):
        alist.append(i)
    return somelist(alist)

my_list = main()   # my_list will save the list return my main function
print my_list
```

you dont need somelist function:

```
 def main():
     alist = []
     for i in range(5):
         alist.append(i)
      return alist          # return alist directly 

 my_list = main()   # my_list will save the list return my main function
 print my_list
```

Comment: Yeah, the OP *did* need somelist(). They state: "I'm trying to make a program that requires me to pass more than one list to a function.". Somelist was the function to which they passed a list

Comment: @kdopen if Op need the function he can follow the 1st two

Comment: Where does the "If" in "If Op need the function" come from? As they stated, that is the most important thing they are trying to learn. Your final example doesn't pass a list to *anything* (other than implicitly as *self* in the alist.append() call)

Comment: @kdopen whatever you trying to say its completely base less, i covered most of the things

Answer (score -1):

The somelist() function is fine. The problem is that main() isn't returning anything after calling somelist().

A function which exits either by falling off the end (as yours does) or with a plain 'return' statement actually returns None

Change the last line of main() to

```
return somelist(alist)
```

then, you will need to print the results of the call to main() to see what it returns if you are not in a REPL.

Comment: Works for me. Take the OP's code, including the module-level call to main(). Change the last line of main() as I said (and as you did in your second example). Put it all in test.py and run 'python test.py'. You see '[0,1,2,3,4]' printed on the screen

Comment: My bad - I spend so much time in a REPL I forget the interpreter behaves differently and doesn't actually print out the results of main()

Comment: Seriously? Someone is now childishly downvoting my answers to other questions as well as this one - including an answer that is 3 years old?